# Let $\gcd({p, q)} = 1$. Prove that $\sum_{k = 1}^{q - 1}\left\lfloor k \cdot \frac{p}{q} \right\rfloor = \frac{(p - 1)(q - 1)}{2}$.

Tags: number-theory

> Let $\gcd({p, q)} = 1$. Prove that $$\large \sum_{k = 1}^{q - 1}\left\lfloor k \cdot \frac{p}{q} \right\rfloor = \frac{(p - 1)(q - 1)}{2}$$

We are learning something called "hệ thặng dư (đầy đủ)" in Vietnamese. I've decided to call it a "total surplus set" in English since I can't a definition of it on Wikipedia.

(Update: Thanks to [Matthew Daly](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3402897/let-gcdp-q-1-prove-that-sum-k-1q-1-left-lfloor-k-cdot-fr/3402898?#comment6999604_3402898), I have found out that the English phrase I was looking for is "complete residue system".)

I would like to know whether the below solution is correct. Thanks so much if you have given me feedback on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\gcd(p, q) = 1$, we have that $A = \{p, 2p, \cdots, (q - 2)p, (q - 1)p\}$ is a complete residue system of modulo $q$.

$$\implies \left\{\left\{\frac{p}{q}\right\}, \left\{\frac{2p}{q}\right\}, \cdots, \left\{\frac{(q - 2)p}{q}\right\}, \left\{\frac{(q - 1)p}{q}\right\}\right\} = \left\{\frac{1}{q}, \frac{2}{q}, \cdots, \frac{q - 2}{q}, \frac{q - 1}{q}\right\}$$

$$\implies \sum_{k = 1}^{q - 1}\left\{ k \cdot \frac{p}{q} \right\} = \frac{1 + 2 + \cdots + (q - 2) + (q - 1)}{q} = \frac{q - 1}{2}$$

It is obvious that $$\sum_{k = 1}^{q - 1}\left\lfloor k \cdot \frac{p}{q} \right\rfloor = \sum_{k = 1}^{q - 1}\left(k \cdot \frac{p}{q}\right) - \sum_{k = 1}^{q - 1}\left\{ k \cdot \frac{p}{q} \right\} = \frac{p(q - 1)}{2} - \frac{q - 1}{2} = \frac{(p - 1)(q - 1)}{2}$$

Comment: I believe the English phrase for what you are describing is a "complete residue system", except that has to have a member for all $n+1$ different possibilities.

Comment: That was a typo. I apologize for that.